# Kafka Stream DSL non-key join current workaround explained

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to understand the workaround that is mentioned in:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3705

as in

> Today in Kafka Streams DSL, KTable joins are only based on keys. If
>   users want to join a KTable A by key a with another KTable B by key b
>   but with a "foreign key" a, and assuming they are read from two topics
>   which are partitioned on a and b respectively, they need to do the
>   following pattern:
>
> ```
> tableB' = tableB.groupBy(/* select on field "a" */).agg(...); // now tableB' is partitioned on "a"
>
> tableA.join(tableB', joiner);
> ```

I have a hard time to understand what is exactly happening.

In particular that sentence is confusing: *"If users want to join a KTable A by key a with another KTable B by key b but with a "foreign key" a"*. Also i do not understand the code above either.

Can someone clarify a bit what is happening here ?

This is also mentioned here:

Close the gap between the semantics of KTables in streams and tables in relational databases. It is common practice to capture changes as they are made to tables in a RDBMS into Kafka topics (JDBC-connect, Debezium, Maxwell). These entities typically have multiple one-to-many relationship. Usually RDBMSs offer good support to resolve this relationship with a join. Streams falls short here and the workaround **(group by - join - lateral view)** is not well supported as well and is not in line with the idea of record based processing. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-213+Support+non-key+joining+in+KTable

What means **(group by - join - lateral view)** ? I suspect it is related to the code above, but again a bit hard to follow. Could any one shed some light on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the below code is the pseudocode for joining two KTables with non-key join:

```
tableB' = tableB.groupBy(/* select on field "a" */).agg(...); // now tableB' is partitioned on "a"

tableA.join(tableB', joiner);
```

**Explanation** :

Let's say, **tableA** has a key field "**a**". In order to join another ktable with **tableA**, it should be co-partitioned. It should have same keys. Hence we will rekey the ktable **tableB** with field "**a**"

```
tableB' = tableB.groupBy(/* select on field "a" */).agg(...); // now tableB' is partitioned on "a"
```

`groupBy()` is shorthand for `selectKey()+ groupByKey()` operation.

`groupBy(/* select on field "a" */)` will rekey the **tableB** on field **"a"** and group by that key. Hence now you have a KGroupedTable having field "**a**" as key. In order to get KTable, you need to call .aggregate() on this. That is what happening in above code.

***P.S. `.agg()` should be renamed with `.aggregate()`***

Once **tableB'** is ready, you can join with **tableA** using below code.

```
tableA.join(tableB', joiner);
```

Here joiner refers to `ValueJoiner` implementation.

**Example** :

```
// Java 8+ example, using lambda expressions
KTable<String, String> joined = left.join(right, 
     /* Below line is ValueJoiner */
    (leftValue, rightValue) -> "left=" + leftValue + ", right=" + rightValue 
  );
```

At the moment, this is the way for Non-key join on KTables
You can find nice explanation in documents : https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#ktable-ktable-join

Comment: Can this be expressed with KSQL directly ?

Comment: Yes, you can do with KSQL as well. https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/partition-data.html

Comment: The step that i don't see in the example KSQL example is the aggregation. Indeed without aggregation, record will be overwritten. What i am mean is that to my understanding, PartitionBy is just the rekeying but without grouping and aggregating. At least this is not mention in the example. Could you clarify on this ?

Comment: Why not using GroupBy and something like CollectList, followed by PartitionBY if the first part does not rekey already.

Comment: Yes, you are right Above code case be used in KSQL in following `SELECT  user, COLLECT_LIST(URL_EXTRACT_PATH(url)) AS CLICK_PATH FROM clicks    GROUP BY user`.  But to be noticed `COLLECT_LIST` support only single column.

Comment: Do you still need a partition by after or it is implicit as in the Kafka stream code ?

Comment: yes, `PARTITION BY` is only for rekeying. If you use `GROUP BY`, no need to specify `PARTITION BY`. It will be implicit in groupby operation.

Comment: Sounds like COLLECT_LIST has an annoying Limit. 1000 records and the rest is ignored. I wonder if we could implement an UDF that has no limit, that we would only use in the Case of KTable. Any hint on some code sample or direction on how to do that, and if there is any known problem to that ? Why is there this arbitrary limit, can it not be set trough configuration ?

Comment: Well, this is how, it is set on [COLLECT_LIST](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/51b8f61f17e01617673f2221083f0d4df582f9cf/ksql-engine/src/main/java/io/confluent/ksql/function/udaf/array/CollectListUdaf.java)  implementation source code. You can't change it at the moment. You can implement your own UDAF in similar way and follow the steps [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/implement-a-udf.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for all your support so far, really bigs thanks. Will ask one last on this, can you point me to the source code for collect_list ? I will start from there :)

Comment: It's already there in previous comment- Github link. Just click on the link, and you are there :)

Comment: there is just one issue with your answer: << groupBy(/* select on field "a" */) will rekey the tableB on field "a" and group by that key>>>. If if you rekey Table B on field a, then you will loose data, given that it is a KTable ? I would rather think that first you group and then you rekey ? Else there must be some detail that i don't see ....

Comment: selectKey operation in groupBy() affects  how you want to aggregate the information. You need to decide, in your case, if you want to  make a list, based on key "a" or "b".  Based on that you choose to peform selectKey operation.  You don't loose any data KTable is rekeyed.

Comment: Do you have link to some doc that describe the internal of that. I'm actually curious to know how it work, without necessarily surfacing the all logic by myself in readying the all code.